# how to i determine if a user got to a page by pressing the back button

Tags: html

How can I tell if I user visited a page on my website by pressing the back button instead of clicking a link?  I am trying to show one page if a person clicked a link to go to the website vs going from history vs from a bookmark.  Does HTML show where the user was last?

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture the *back button* event because there is none.

You could access the browsers history through the `History` object. Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

If you want to support older browsers there is a `History.js` which allows for backwards compatibility available at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

You can also use your web server logs or stats package to determine if someone clicked a link to your website (referral). If coming from a bookmark if would count as a direct entry to the page.